# Why am I getting Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Line 12

Tags: sql, t-sql

Firstly I have seen the answers to this question and they do not apply to me. I have the same amount of columns in both my SELECT and INSERT statements. Please help, I have spent half a day on this. When I run it, it works perfectly but it gives me an error after the last iteration.

> Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 The select list for the INSERT
>   statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of
>   SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.

```
proc [dbo].[uspPOP_WBC] 

--params
(@ptblname  varchar(MAX)        
,@pID_Sub varchar               
,@pSubCodeShort  varchar(2)     
,@pdbname  varchar(10)  )       
AS 
BEGIN
SET nocount ON; 
DECLARE @strSQL AS nvarchar(MAX)

SET @strSQL = 'INSERT INTO dbo.WBC 
( ID
, ID_SUB
, wellcompl
, id_wellcompl
, id_type_wellcompl
, type_wellcompl
, id_wellstring
, wellstring
, type_wellstring
, start_date
, end_date
, comment)'
SET @strSQL = @strSQL + 
' SELECT WC.id
,'+convert(varchar(1),@pID_Sub)+'   
, WC.name
, WC.id 
, WC.id_type_wellcompl
, TWC.name
, WC.id_wellstring
, WS.name
, TWS.name
, WC.start_date
, WC.end_date
, WC.comment
 FROM (
 ['+ @pdbname+ @pSubCodeShort +'].[dbo].[wellbore_compl] as WC 
INNER JOIN ['+@pdbname+ @pSubCodeShort+'].[dbo].[wellstring] as WS 
ON WC.id_wellstring = WS.id 
INNER JOIN ['+@pdbname+ @pSubCodeShort+'].[dbo].[type_wellcompl] as TWC 
ON WC.id_type_wellcompl = TWC.id
INNER JOIN ['+@pdbname+ @pSubCodeShort+'].[dbo].[type_wellstring] as TWS 
ON WS.id_type_wellstring = TWS.id)
where WC.deletedAt is null'
;

EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL
SET nocount OFF; 
END
```

Printout of @strSQL

```
    INSERT INTO dbo.WBC ( ID, ID_SUB, wellcompl, id_wellcompl,  
id_type_wellcompl, type_wellcompl, id_wellstring, wellstring, 
type_wellstring, start_date, end_date, comment) 
SELECT 
WC.id
, 1 
, WC.name
, WC.id 
, WC.id_type_wellcompl
, TWC.name
, WC.id_wellstring
, WS.name
, TWS.name
, WC.start_date
, WC.end_date
, WC.comment
 FROM (
 [PDS_SYNC_CM].[dbo].[wellbore_compl] as WC INNER JOIN [PDS_SYNC_CM].[dbo].[wellstring] as WS ON WC.id_wellstring = WS.id 
 INNER JOIN [PDS_SYNC_CM].[dbo].[type_wellcompl] as TWC ON WC.id_type_wellcompl = TWC.id
 INNER JOIN [PDS_SYNC_CM].[dbo].[type_wellstring] as TWS ON WS.id_type_wellstring = TWS.id)
 where WC.deletedAt is null
```

Comment: do `Print @strSQL` before executing, and running it as a query the you will have more clue what is wrong

Comment: The reason i convert the @pID_Sub is because it was originally declared as INT. I was just trying to see if that was the problem but forgot to change it back before I posted. If I treat it as varchar throughout it still gives the error. Sorry.

Comment: I meant, it's hard to find us what is wrong, if you print the sql statement either you will find what is wrong or if you add it to your question then we can help more

Comment: @ RezaRahmati
Thanks. It runs without error. I don't know how to add the sql code to my question, there must be a way to edit it but I can't find it.

Comment: Do you still have any issue? (or your question is answered?)

Comment: My question remains, I still get the error but the code itself runs without error???

Comment: so would you update your question and paste the content of strSQL there?

Comment: @JohnBrewster - You can edit your question by clicking the `edit` link at the bottom of the question itself.

Comment: Okay done, thanks.

Comment: The error message couldn't be any clearer, " the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list".  What else can we tell you???  Count how many items in your Insert, then count how many items in your select.

Comment: @Eric, thanks for taking the time to read and answer my question. I have counted and they both have 12 items, that's the problem and it has not been answered. As can be seen by the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

If my counting is correct the code has twelve columns in the INSERT clause and only eleven in the SELECT clause.  One is missing, so please review your columns to figure out which one is missing and add it.

Comment: I'm counting 12 in both. The first one is just way over at the end of the line with the list of insert columns.